# fscanf format %[variable length]s

Tags: c, scanf

I'm wondering how can I get variable length word with fscanf :

I was doing something like :

```
char w[WORD_LENGTH_MAX + 1];
fscanf(f1, "%" XSTR(WORD_LENGTH_MAX) "s", w);
```

but can't use preprocessor anymore because I want WORD_LENGTH_MAX to be variable, actually coming from argv.
Now I have something like this :

```
length = argv[0];
w[length + 1];
fscanf(f1, "%" ???length??? "s", w);
```

but don't know how to make this to work

Comment: You can build your format string using e.g.: `sprintf`

Comment: Your title is a little misleading as it implies the `%[...]` format specifier, which many beginners mistakenly end with an `s`. Perhaps you should say something about "%s scanf specifier with field width from variable" or similar, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the format string with `snprintf`:

```
    int length = atoi(argv[0]);
    w[length + 1];
    char fmt[20];
    snprintf(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%%%ds", length);
    fscanf(f1, fmt, w);
```

Yet a simpler solution is to use a `while` loop:

```
    int length = atoi(argv[0]);
    w[length + 1];
    int c, i = 0;
    while (i <= length && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            break;
        }
        w[i++] = c;
    }
    w[i] = '\0';
```